# Definition of l1_regularization_strength and l2_regularization_strength for Proximal Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Tensor-flow has proximal gradient descent optimizer which can be called as:

```
loss = Y-w*x # example of a loss function. w-weights to be calculated. x - inputs.

opt=proximal_gradient_descent.ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer(learningrate,l1_regularization_strength, l2_regularization_strength)

opt_step= opt.minimize(loss)
```

Since we know that proximal gradient descent takes l1-norm and l2-norm as regularization, here comes my question: **Should I include the part of l1/l2 norm in my loss or I should just use something looks like my loss above?**

Also, it seems that ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer is defined under proximal_gradient_descent while minimize is defined under optimizer. I don't know if the regularization_strength can be passed over to optimizer.

Someone who has ideas about the questions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe I understand your question. Are you asking whether you need to change anything else in that code for those weight regularization algorithms to work?

Comment: Yes, so if I define my loss as `loss = Y-w*x`, I suppose I am using the regularization of the algo and should give regularization weights. But if I define my loss as `loss = Y-w*x + l1_norm + l2_norm` I don't know how to assign values to the regularization weights.

Comment: Well no, you don't have to do that. I still wonder what leads you to think that adding `l1_norm` and `l2_norm` to the resulting loss value is appropriate. These hyperparameters should only influence how the gradients are calculated, and that is already done by the optimizer.

Comment: Okay, so I guess the loss should only be `Y-w*x`. And I am still wondering how the two hyper parameters are being used by tensorflow. As I mentioned, minimize() doesn't take them as input. Thanks!

Comment: They are usually defined in each layer with weight variables, but that depends on what you are using for this. If you create a [MCVE] of the issue, that may be found out much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is using a tensorflow optimizer which takes regularization as an optimizer parameter do not include the regularization term in your loss function. Many optimizers special-case the regularization and you will end up double-counting or losing the advantages of this special-casing if you also add the regularizers there.